# Sendbird Connection fail : Connection timeout

Tags: react-native, sendbird

I faced an issue - sendbird is always failing the connection and the following error message pops up:

```
{name: "SendBirdException", code: 800190, message: "Connection timeout."}
```

This problem was happening fairly often but not all the time.

May I ask you how to handle the `"Connection timeout."` issue?